# Eclipse, Configuration of Editor

Tags: eclipse, settings

I need to switch to eclipse base on some errors in Netbeans with Android project.
But my problems is I like how Netbeans  look and work and wonder how I can config some part of Eclipse to like more my Netbeans.
( I use eclipse 4.2.1 for Java and Android.)

The first part is, how can I config Eclipse  to always show my the range of a method,
The Eclipse has same function but the range of a method is only show while I hover over the icon with the mouse. ( Also I want this to be square icons )

[image: Image nr 1, Always show the method rang.]

My other question is in netbeans while I has collaps a method I can
preview the method by hover over `{...}`, can I config Eclipse to do same?

[image]

I has identify a working way to show preview,  you move the course to the first line on the collaps lines and then move mouse over the plus sign. But this is more work and take more time then uncollaps and collaps the lines. Is this exist a fast way to do the preview?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse for few years and I have never seen any options or ways to configure preview for collapsed code.

I prefer to use the keyboard instead of the mouse. It's much faster during development for me. I hope those keyboard shortcuts will be useful for you too:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> - collapse 1 level for all blocks **Edit**: (PyDev specific)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> - expand 1 level  for all blocks **Edit**: (PyDev specific)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> - collapse current block
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> - expand current block

For Mac use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

Comment: Sorry the two first short keys not work for me on Windows (laptop).
And yes in some case this is faster but I think this is faster to use the mouse if you only need to overview the this part before edit it.

Comment: Sorry, I see now it's Python plugin specific shortcut. Collapse all with Java editor can be done with: Shift + Ctrl + NUM_KEYPAD_DIVIDE. Yes, during code review or research it's easier to go through the code and definitions with the mouse. Anyway, I am afraid that configuration of code preview is not possible.